# Understanding kubectl run command

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am tryng to create a pod using kubectl run by creating an yaml file, where first command is creating container but showing state as error and second one is creating with out any issue. what is the difference between these commands?

```
master $  kubectl run --restart=Never --image=busybox static-busybox --command -- sleep 1000 --dry-run -o yaml //Error container

master $  kubectl run --restart=Never --image=busybox static-busybox --dry-run -o yaml --command -- sleep 1000 //working command
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first one parameters `--dry-run -o yaml` are applied to the command you run in the container (sleep), in the second one, they are applied to your kubectl execution

Answer (score 1):

As per the syntax of the `kubectl run` `command` needs to be at the end. That's precisely the reason why first command is not working but second one is working.

```
Usage:
  kubectl run NAME --image=image [--env="key=value"] [--port=port] [--dry-run=server|client] [--overrides=inline-json]
[--command] -- [COMMAND] [args...] [options]
```

Comment: but its not documented anywhere that it should specify at the end .

Comment: I agree it could have been specified more explicitly for better understanding

Comment: COuld you let me know how you cracked CKA? I mean suggested references.